# MySQL create tables using a cron job or use Views

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-optimization

I have a number of complex queries, the results of which were being stored in MySQL views. The problem is that MySQL views suffer in performance terms.

I set up a cron job to populate a standard table with the same data that the views were populated with:

```
DROP TABLE user_reports;
CREATE TABLE user_reports
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM 
  /** COMPLEX QUERY **/
;
```

Now, when making queries on the cron-populated `user_reports` table, **queries take almost a tenth of the time to query** compared with the equivalent view.

Is this a common approach? Obviously there is some burden on the server every time the CRON job is run and it means that data is not available *live*.

> Time taken to query `user_reports` = 0.002 seconds
>   Time taken to query `view_user_reports` = 0.018 seconds

This all said, maybe a query that takes 0.018 seconds to run should be run from application code, rather than stored in views? Although I don't think it would scale as well as the cron-driven method.

Comment: Let me just clarify this - you have a view which is basically a product of various joins of multiple tables. Then, you query the view and it takes 18 milliseconds, which isn't satisfying so you decided to do exactly what? Create a new table that gets filled with data from where? How'd you fill them in? Did you run EXPLAIN for your queries on the reports to see what the bottleneck is? Querying joined tables is always slower than querying a single table with complex WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the results of which were being stored in MySQL views

Oh dear. MySQL views DO NOT store data.

> DROP TABLE user_reports;
>
> CREATE TABLE user_reports

...something wrong with....

```
TRUNCATE TABLE user_reports;
```

?

> I don't think it would scale as well as the cron-driven method

Only as long as the query in the cron job doesn't take long to run - when it does you'll need to start thinking about incrementally adding data to the pre-processed result set. But at 0.018 secs, this is just premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks so pre-processing data in this way is common. Glad you commented on the 0.018 seconds since I didn't think this was particularly intensive. This will be useful to me in a number of projects.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases an 18 ms db search isn't adversely affecting performance. If it is, then it is common to use some kind of caching. If you need to be able to do searches on the data and it's ok if the data is a trifle old, then your approach is good.

If you don't need to be able to search the data, then the cache can be stored directly in memory or in a file, preferbly in the same format as it is to be delivered to the clients.